# Python equivalent fo hive NumericHistogram

Tags: python, hive, pypy

I have a python(to be more specific -- pypy compatible) code. I have to use histograms in it, which should be very similar if not exactly same as [this](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/NumericHistogram.java) java histogram implementation in Hive project. Numpy has a histogram [implementation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html). 
Does anyone know if these two are equivalent in use or can be made by choosing appropriate parameter values? I can find this by reading the codes, though checking here if someone already knows this.

Comment: What do you mean by equivalent? They both make histograms.

Comment: @Denziloe If they do any approximations in storing the large values. Do they do in the same way? The way, I can choose bin boundaries and number of bins etc.

Comment: Also, the way algorithms adjust introduction of new bins.
Actually, the java implementation follows the algorithm given in [this][1] paper.
[1] Yael Ben-Haim and Elad Tom-Tov, "A streaming parallel decision tree algorithm",
 * J. Machine Learning Research 11 (2010), pp. 849--872

Comment: Could you post pairs of input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Long answer, TLDR in bold**

You can just compile and run both instead of trying to theory craft and guess at what the code does. When in doubt, just run it. With a little bit of work, you can get `NumericHistogram.java` that you linked to compile without maven and just using a CLI `javac` call (just delete the references to the `hive` packages and associated methods).

**I simply tested both on the array** `[0,1,...,98,99]`.

### Java version (java 10.0.2):

**EDIT: Received feedback (by email) to include the Java code. Here it is (removed docstrings and some comments, and didn't include all the public methods):**

```
/*                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one                                                                                                                                               
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file                                                                                                                                             
 * distributed with this work for additional information                                                                                                                                                    
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file                                                                                                                                               
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the                                                                                                                                                        
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance                                                                                                                                               
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at                                                                                                                                               
 *                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0                                                                                                                                                           
 *                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software                                                                                                                                      
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,                                                                                                                                        
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.                                                                                                                                 
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and                                                                                                                                      
 * limitations under the License.                                                                                                                                                                           
 */

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class NumericHistogram {
    static class Coord implements Comparable {
        double x;
        double y;

        public int compareTo(Object other) {
            return Double.compare(x, ((Coord) other).x);
        }
    };

    // Class variables                                                                                                                                                                                      
    private int nbins;
    private int nusedbins;
    private ArrayList<Coord> bins;
    private Random prng;

    public NumericHistogram() {
        nbins = 0;
        nusedbins = 0;
        bins = null;

        // init the RNG for breaking ties in histogram merging. A fixed seed is specified here                                                                                                              
        // to aid testing, but can be eliminated to use a time-based seed (which would                                                                                                                      
        // make the algorithm non-deterministic).                                                                                                                                                           
        prng = new Random(31183);
    }

    public void reset() {
        bins = null;
        nbins = nusedbins = 0;
    }

    public int getUsedBins() {
        return nusedbins;
    }

    public boolean isReady() {
        return nbins != 0;
    }

    public Coord getBin(int b) {
        return bins.get(b);
    }

    public void allocate(int num_bins) {
        nbins = num_bins;
        bins = new ArrayList<Coord>();
        nusedbins = 0;
    }

    public void add(double v) {
        int bin = 0;
        for(int l=0, r=nusedbins; l < r; ) {
            bin = (l+r)/2;
            if (bins.get(bin).x > v) {
                r = bin;
            } else {
                if (bins.get(bin).x < v) {
                    l = ++bin;
                } else {
                    break; // break loop on equal comparator                                                                                                                                                
                }
            }
        }
        if (bin < nusedbins && bins.get(bin).x == v) {
            bins.get(bin).y++;
        } else {
            Coord newBin = new Coord();
            newBin.x = v;
            newBin.y = 1;
            bins.add(bin, newBin);

            // Trim the bins down to the correct number of bins.                                                                                                                                            
            if (++nusedbins > nbins) {
                trim();
            }
        }

    }

    private void trim() {
        while(nusedbins > nbins) {
            // Find the closest pair of bins in terms of x coordinates. Break ties randomly.                                                                                                                
            double smallestdiff = bins.get(1).x - bins.get(0).x;
            int smallestdiffloc = 0, smallestdiffcount = 1;
            for(int i = 1; i < nusedbins-1; i++) {
                double diff = bins.get(i+1).x - bins.get(i).x;
                if(diff < smallestdiff)  {
                    smallestdiff = diff;
                    smallestdiffloc = i;
                    smallestdiffcount = 1;
                } else {
                    if(diff == smallestdiff && prng.nextDouble() <= (1.0/++smallestdiffcount) ) {
                        smallestdiffloc = i;
                    }
                }
            }

            double d = bins.get(smallestdiffloc).y + bins.get(smallestdiffloc+1).y;
            Coord smallestdiffbin = bins.get(smallestdiffloc);
            smallestdiffbin.x *= smallestdiffbin.y / d;
            smallestdiffbin.x += bins.get(smallestdiffloc+1).x / d * bins.get(smallestdiffloc+1).y;
            smallestdiffbin.y = d;
            // Shift the remaining bins left one position                                                                                                                                                   
            bins.remove(smallestdiffloc+1);
            nusedbins--;
        }
    }

    public int getNumBins() {
        return bins == null ? 0 : bins.size();
    }
}
```

I inserted this main into the `NumericHistogram` class (see above):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NumericHistogram hist = new NumericHistogram();
    hist.allocate(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        hist.add(i);
    }

    ArrayList<Coord> bins = new ArrayList<Coord>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        bins.add(hist.getBin(i));
    }

    int index = 0;
    for (Coord bin : bins) {
        System.out.println(index + "th bin x: " + bin.x);
        System.out.println(index + "th bin y: " + bin.y);
        index++;
    }
}
```

This output:

```
Matthews-MacBook-Pro:stackoverflow matt$ java NumericHistogram
0th bin x: 2.0
0th bin y: 5.0
1th bin x: 9.5
1th bin y: 10.0
2th bin x: 21.5
2th bin y: 14.0
3th bin x: 33.0
3th bin y: 9.0
4th bin x: 44.0
4th bin y: 13.0
5th bin x: 55.0
5th bin y: 9.0
6th bin x: 64.5
6th bin y: 10.0
7th bin x: 75.5
7th bin y: 12.0
8th bin x: 88.0
8th bin y: 13.0
9th bin x: 97.0
9th bin y: 5.0
```

### Python version:

The `numpy` version was a bit different. Here's the script:

```
import numpy as np

hist = np.histogram(np.arange(100)) # 10 is the default for num bins
print(hist)
```

This output:

```
(array([10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]), array([ 0. ,  9.9, 19.8, 29.7, 39.6, 49.5, 59.4, 69.3, 79.2, 89.1, 99. ]))
```

To compare to the java version, we'd really have to zip them, which you can do like this:

```
y_values, x_values = hist
i = 0
for x_val, y_val in zip(x_values, y_values):
    print(str(i) + "th bin x: " + str(x_val))
    print(str(i) + "th bin y: " + str(y_val))
    i += 1
```

and it output:

```
0th bin x: 0.0
0th bin y: 10
1th bin x: 9.9
1th bin y: 10
2th bin x: 19.8
2th bin y: 10
3th bin x: 29.700000000000003
3th bin y: 10
4th bin x: 39.6
4th bin y: 10
5th bin x: 49.5
5th bin y: 10
6th bin x: 59.400000000000006
6th bin y: 10
7th bin x: 69.3
7th bin y: 10
8th bin x: 79.2
8th bin y: 10
9th bin x: 89.10000000000001
9th bin y: 10
```

### Summary and making them match:

**Are they equivalent? No, they are not equivalent.** They're using different partitioning schemes to assign values to bins. Java version puts the item in the "closest" bin using rounding rules, whereas `numpy` is doing a range grouping (i.e. 0-9.9, 9.9-19.8, ..., 89.1-100). Furthermore, the default bins they generate are also not the same, which kind of makes sense since the schemes are so different.

**Can I get them to match? Yes, but you'll have to figure out how to generate random numbers *exactly* like Java in the Python realm if you want a general implementation.**. I tried copying the implementation, and I got it to work, but I'm unable to get the random numbers to be the same. Even if you're using `numpy` instead of copying the logic to Python, you'll *still* have to be able to generate Java's random numbers in order to get them to match in the general case. This project seemed relevant, but it's only Java 6 RNG, not later versions of Java: https://github.com/MostAwesomeDude/java-random. At risk of making this giant answer even longer, here's the Python code to copy the Java implementation:

```
""" Just a mindless copy for easy verification. Not good style or performant. """
import random
class Coord:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)

    def __repr__(self): # debug
        return "Coord(" + str(self.x) + ", " + str(self.y) + ")"

    def __str__(self): # debug
        return "Coord(" + str(self.x) + ", " + str(self.y) + ")"

class Random:
    """ This class needs fixin. You'll have to do some work here to make it match your version of Java. """
    def __init__(self, seed):
        random.seed(seed)

    def nextDouble(self):
        return random.uniform(0, 1)

class NumericHistogram:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nbins = 0
        self.nusedbins = 0
        self.bins = None

        self.prng = Random(31183) # This should behave the same as Java's RNG for your Java version.                                                                                                        

    def allocate(self, num_bins):
        self.nbins = num_bins
        self.bins = []
        self.nusedbins = 0

    def add(self, v):
        bin = 0

        l = 0
        r = self.nusedbins
        while(l < r):
            bin = (l+r)//2
            if self.bins[bin].x > v:
                r = bin
            else:
                if self.bins[bin].x < v:
                    l = bin + 1; bin += 1
                else:
                    break

        if bin < self.nusedbins and self.bins[bin].x == v:
            self.bins[bin].y += 1
        else:
            newBin = Coord(x=v, y=1)
            if bin == len(self.bins):
                self.bins.append(newBin)
            else:
                self.bins[bin] == newBin

            self.nusedbins += 1
            if (self.nusedbins > self.nbins):
                self.trim()
    def trim(self):
        while self.nusedbins > self.nbins:
            smallestdiff = self.bins[1].x - self.bins[0].x
            smallestdiffloc = 0
            smallestdiffcount = 1
            for i in range(1, self.nusedbins-1):
                diff = self.bins[i+1].x - self.bins[i].x
                if diff < smallestdiff:
                    smallestdiff = diff
                    smallestdiffloc = i
                    smallestdiffcount = 1
                else:
                    smallestdiffcount += 1
                    if diff == smallestdiff and self.prng.nextDouble() <= (1.0/smallestdiffcount):
                        smallestdiffloc = i

            d = self.bins[smallestdiffloc].y + self.bins[smallestdiffloc+1].y
            smallestdiffbin = self.bins[smallestdiffloc]
            smallestdiffbin.x *= smallestdiffbin.y / d
            smallestdiffbin.x += self.bins[smallestdiffloc+1].x / d * self.bins[smallestdiffloc+1].y
            smallestdiffbin.y = d
            self.bins.pop(smallestdiffloc+1)
            self.nusedbins -= 1
```

And the "main":

```
hist = NumericHistogram()
hist.allocate(10)
for i in range(100):
    hist.add(i)

for ind, bin in enumerate(hist.bins):
    print(str(ind) + "th bin x: " + str(bin.x))
    print(str(ind) + "th bin y: " + str(bin.y))
```

this outputs:

```
0th bin x: 4.0
0th bin y: 9.0
1th bin x: 13.0
1th bin y: 9.0
2th bin x: 24.0
2th bin y: 13.0
3th bin x: 35.0
3th bin y: 9.0
4th bin x: 46.5
4th bin y: 14.0
5th bin x: 57.5
5th bin y: 8.0
6th bin x: 66.0
6th bin y: 9.0
7th bin x: 76.49999999999999
7th bin y: 12.0
8th bin x: 88.99999999999999
8th bin y: 13.0
9th bin x: 97.5
9th bin y: 4.0
```

**So it's kind of close, but no bananas. The difference is down to the RNG (as far as I can tell). I don't know a lot about Java `Random` or RNGs in general: so it might be best to just post *another* question here on SO about how to generate random numbers *exactly* like Java [insert-your-java-version-here].**

HTH and can get you started in the right direction.